# read from all files in a folder to external tables oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote an sql statement like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE TableA 
   (    "Col1" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "Col2" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 

   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DIR"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( records delimited by newline
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
    )
      LOCATION
       ( 'TableA.csv'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

There are 120 .csv files in my 'DIR' directory. I need to read in each of the file and create separate external tables for each file. For example tableA has to be created for fileA. 
Is it possible to write a procedure for this, reading each filename into a loop and substituting the filename variable into the above sql state and running the sql statement within the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem a few years ago, and I used this procedure provided by Tom Kyte in his world famous asktom.oracle.com:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584

Basically, you have to create a java procedure that reads the directory, and then a PL/SQL stored procedure that uses that java procedure to read the files in the directories.

Take a look at it, and tell me how it goes...I'm looking for my code that I made for that years ago, but can't seem to find it. It was at a different job.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you so much. I tried to run the java stored proc, it showed me *Cause:    An attempt was made to use a Java command when Java is not installed.
*Action:   Install Java, or do not use the command. Im not sure why it is saying java is not installed. How can we install sqldeveloper if there is no java in the first place? it seems like it is looking for elsewhere

Comment: Maybe it's in the server side? I really don't know...I'll look it up.

Comment: Are you using oracle XE (Express Edition)? Apparently, the Java code won't work in that edition.

Comment: yes i checked it just now, using express edition. But thank you so much for your help, i too have seen the same links when i was searching.